# What is c in R Language

Tags: r

I am trying to understand a script using R Language. here is the snippet code:

```
finalList <- unique(c(unique(tble1$Product),unique(tble2$Data$Product),unique(tble3$Product),unique(tble4$Product)))
```

What does this do?

Comment: Type `?c` in your console and press Enter: c {base}  Combine Values into a Vector or List....

Comment: Does this mean it create a list with the product values in it.?

Comment: If all arguments are vectors, then the return value is a vector. If one or more of its args is a list, then it combines all of them into a list and returns it as such. The [`?c`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) help page goes through this with example code. This function is for `c`oncatenation of vectors/lists. In python, lists are combined with the `+` operator, as in `[0,1] + [2,3]` --> `[0,1,2,3]`; in R, that's `c(c(0,1), c(2,3))` or `c(0:1, 2:3)`, depending.

Comment: I removed the [tag:database] tag, not sure why that was assigned. The tag-recommendation system here on Stack is flawed, please look them through when asking questions. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `?c` is identical to typing `help("c")` in R.